# JSR 303 throw exception on any constraint violation

Tags: java, validation, hibernate-validator

I am using `Hibernate Validator API` to validate the fields on my objects. The example of how it looks is below.

```
@NotNull @Size(min = 3, max = 8) String name;
@NotNull @Size(min = 3, max = 16) String surname;
@Size(min = 3, max = 10) String company;
// ...
```

Now the problem with this is that I am able to construct my object and no exception is thrown. For example.

```
Person p = new Person("a", "b", "c");
```

This doesn't throw any runtime exceptions, instead creates an object with violated constraints. And in order to obtain the violated constraints, a `Validator` instance should be called explicitly from the client code. I'm not entirely sure why they made it that way, but I need the construction of an object to fail with some exception if the object's fields are violated. That way something like:

```
Person p = new Person("a", "b", "c");
```

... would throw an exception. And the invalid object could not be created. This is my desired behaviour.

Is that possible to achieve?

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you just check the values within ctor when creating an object?

```
public Person(String name, String surname, String company) {
    if(name == null || name.length() < 3) {
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("useful message")
    }
}
```

However, I suppose that these annotations only work when saving objects to DB.

Comment: You understnd this is just a basic example trying to explain my requirement? The real object has 30 fields, uses a builder pattern etc so something like you suggest is impossible. Like i said, i need the construction to fail if the constraints are violated

Answer (score 0):

Hibernate Validator can't magically intercept your constructors to execute the validation.

So you need something to do that.

You can probably achieve what you want by instrumenting the classes (with ByteBuddy or something similar) but I'm not sure I would recommend that.

The easiest way is for you to create a service or something similar that instantiates your object and then execute the validation on it.

Comment: The problem with instantiate object and validate it inside a service (or sth similar) is that my objects are created with builder. The only way then would be to have the validation inside the build method which doesn't seem right? And also quite tricky to implement (but probably possible) when you're using AutoValue.Builder which I am

Comment: You can try instrumenting your classes with ByteBuddy. Not sure it's going to be easier though.